# Shorten the delay from the onclick event on touchscreen devices

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

**Note:** This question is purely hypothetical, I am well aware of touch events.

I have a large amount of html that has the `onclick` event attribute attached to many of the html tags. The problem is that there is a small delay on touchscreen devices with the `onclick` event. This is very annoying and makes things feel less responsive and slow, so I would like to know if you can control the delay time of `onclick`, so it can be manipulated to feel like a touch event.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable zoom for instant onClick.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

The delay occurs because the phone is waiting for the second tap to zoom in.

Comment: Although this helps, it is still slightly slower than `ontouchstart`. Also, your solution does not give me any control over the delay, although the viewport change was interesting, not what I expected at all.